# How can I force perl to process args ONLY from stdin and not from a file on command line?

Tags: perl

If I have this inline command:

```
perl -pi -e 's/([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})\s?/\\x$1\\x$2\t/g'
```

Which is simply to substitute four-digit hex, and add it a 'x' in front. `-i` used with no filenames on the command line, reading from `STDIN`. So for params: `0000 0776`, results are `\x00\x00\x07\x76`

I know, that if `-n` or `-p` (with printing) called, perl takes `<>` diamond. But I want to pass args only AFTER command, but perl assumes it as files to read. So how do I force `-n` or `-p` to regard args after command to be regular args for `<>` in program, and not args as files to read?

Also, I do not understand the role of `i` here. If i would not include it, then I would be adding args line after line (as does `<>`), but with `i`, it takes all my args at once?

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking, but if you want to be processing STDIN, it makes no sense to have `-i`, so maybe remove it?

Comment: Why are there other arguments to your program? You're leaving out quite a bit of context that would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are no arguments (i.e., if `@ARGV` is empty), then your one-line script (which implicitly uses `<>`) will read input from `STDIN`. So the solution is to clear `@ARGV` at compile time.

```
perl -pi -e 'BEGIN{@ARGV=()}
             s/([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})\s?/\\x$1\\x$2\t/g'
```

---

Another solution: Force `ARGV` (the implicit file handle that the base `<>` operator reads from) to point to `STDIN`. This solution doesn't clobber your `@ARGV`, if any.

```
perl -pi -e 'BEGIN{*ARGV=*STDIN}
             s/([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})\s?/\\x$1\\x$2\t/g'
```

Comment: I'm wary of the second option, only because `*ARGV` is somewhat magical (so that it can open STDIN or each file, and continue after reaching the end of each file).

Comment: @Grinnz, `*ARGV{IO}` is magical, but the glob itself isn't. But I wouldn't use either of these. No reason to avoid `while (<STDIN>)`

Answer (score 4):

The -p option is equivalent to the [following code](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-p):

```
LINE:
  while (<>) {
      ...             # your program goes here
  } continue {
      print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
  }
```

-n is the same without the continue block. There's no way to change what it reads from (which is unfortunate, since `<<>>` and `<STDIN>` are both safer options), but it's pretty easy to replicate it with your modification (the error checking is rarely necessary here):

```
perl -e 'while (<STDIN>) { s/([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})\s?/\\x$1\\x$2\t/g } continue { print }'
```

Comment: `} continue { print }` can be simplified to `; print }`